# fleqn, koma-script and align: fleqn doesn't work properly

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, align

I have a problem using koma-script classes, fleqn and align: The equation are not completely left aligned. The fleqn option moves them to the left , but the equation are not left aligned. In my main file I put:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amu_these}
```

An example of what I get is:

[image]

Here is a part of my style sheet.
Thanks for your help.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{amu_these}[2012/07/01 Classe personnelle, V0.2]

%%% classe de base (KOMA-Script)
\LoadClass{scrreprt}                    %% classe report (KOMA-Script)
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,DIV=12,BCOR=0mm,twoside=off,index=totoc,listof=totoc}


%%% extensions minimales
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}            %% fontes de caractère
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}     %% format d'encodage
\RequirePackage{lmodern}                %% fontes latin modern
\RequirePackage[french]{babel}      %% typographie française
\RequirePackage[babel]{csquotes}        %% guillemet

\RequirePackage{lipsum}             %% lorem ipsum (exemple)

%%% extensions complémentaires
\RequirePackage{scrhack,scrpage2}   %% macros et en-tête/pied de page     personnalisés (KOMA-Script)
\PassOptionsToPackage{
backend=biber,                  %% default backend of biblatex
maxnames=3,                     %% list names max
minnames=3,                     %% list names min
sorting=none,                       %% sort by name, year, title
citestyle=numeric,          %% numeric citation scheme
bibstyle=ieee,              %%ieee citation scheme
backref=true,                       %% back references (cf. p.)
      url=false,
doi=false
}{biblatex}
\RequirePackage{biblatex}           %% nouvelle façon de gérer ses bibliographies sous LaTeX http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex
\DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{%              %% afiche vol au lieu de t. pour le volume
volume = {vol.},%
number = {n°}
}



\RequirePackage{makeidx}                %% création d'index

 \usepackage{textcomp}  %%% sympboles comme degree


\RequirePackage[titles]{tocloft}        %% TOC LOF LOT
\RequirePackage{endnotes}           %% notes de fin
\RequirePackage{hyperendnotes}      %% !attention! fichier     hyperendnotes.sty hack
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}           %% insertion de pdf
\RequirePackage{graphicx}           %% graphiques et figures
\RequirePackage{caption}                %% légendes des figures
\RequirePackage{array,
multirow,
tabularx}                       %% amélioration des tableaux
\RequirePackage{float}              %% définit les objets flottants tels que les figures et tableaux
\RequirePackage{setspace}           %% modification de l'interligne
\RequirePackage{sectsty}                %% style des section

\RequirePackage[bottom=10em]{geometry}  %% réduit le bas de page pour pouvoir numéroté les pdf insérés (réduire plus si nécessaire)


%%% mathématiques, physique, chimie (à adapter)
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
%renouveller le conteur de notes de bas de page à chaque page:
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

%% charger ce Package en dernier
\RequirePackage{hyperref}           %% pdf interactifs
```

Comment: What you get seems to be the normal output of the `align` environment with `fleqn`, you can align the equal signs using `&` before them. Otherwise you can put a `&` at the start of each line in the equation. (BTW: Instead of writing `exp(x)` it is better to write `\exp(x)` if you are talking about e to the x and not "e times x times p times x".)

Comment: you have not shown your input but if you were using `align` I'd expect the `=` to be aligned????

Answer (score 3):

That's the expected output if you set no alignment point, because the first column in `align` is typeset flush right (and the second column is flush left). In order to get some alignment, you have to set a point. The first example shows your output, the second one has alignment at `=`, the final one is flush left. Note that the third example would better be typeset with `gather` and no `&`; but `align` would come handy for multiple blocks.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
\tau_{n0}=\frac{1}{N_t \sigma_n v_n} \\
\tau_{p0}=\frac{1}{N_t \sigma_p v_p} \\
n_t=n_i\exp(E_t-E_i) \\
p_t=n_i\exp(E_i-E_t)
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
\tau_{n0}&=\frac{1}{N_t \sigma_n v_n} \\
\tau_{p0}&=\frac{1}{N_t \sigma_p v_p} \\
n_t&=n_i\exp(E_t-E_i) \\
p_t&=n_i\exp(E_i-E_t)
\end{align}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{align}
&\tau_{n0}=\frac{1}{N_t \sigma_n v_n} \\
&\tau_{p0}=\frac{1}{N_t \sigma_p v_p} \\
&n_t=n_i\exp(E_t-E_i) \\
&p_t=n_i\exp(E_i-E_t)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]